# Как вывести из бд в обратном порядке?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

У меня есть запрос на получение данных с базы данных, как мне сделать что бы данные с таблицы выводились в обратном порядке? Допустим не `1,2,3 => 3,2,1`

```php
// Запрос на получение данных с одной таблицы
function selectAll($table, $params = []) {
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";

    if(!empty($params)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_numeric($value)) {
                $value = "'".$value."'";
            }
            if ($i === 0) {
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=$value";
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=$value";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Изучите синтаксис SQL и в частности почитайте про ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Если задача, просто вывести все записи отсортированные в обратном порядке, то это выглядит так.

```
$pdo = new PDO("Тут параметры подключения");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from table order by column_name desc"); 
$stmt->execute();
$columns = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Но у вас в коде совсем другое происходит. Вывод всех полей, где столбец равен ключу $key, a значение равно $value.